# ReferenceError: Discord is not defined, at new Discord.Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been following a tutorial to create a Discord bot by CodeLyon. I am up to the point of organizing commands into files. The 'ping' command worked when I was using the basic method in the tutorial, but after trying to use this method my command prompt threw this error when I tried to run it:

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
                      ^

    ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Desktop\VSC 
    Project 1\main.js:10:23)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m
```

I have definitely installed node.js and discord.js, which were issues I saw other people had. However looking around I didn't see anyone with quite my issue so I decided to ask. I am pretty new to applying JavaScript but I know the syntax and some of the basics so I don't think it's that after reading through a few times.
Here is the general area where the error was thrown, it starts at line 1 and the error is at line 10.

```
const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
// Lines 1 & 2 were changed from original tutorial in order to fix the Intents not defined error

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');


client.commands = new Discord.Collection(); // * Error is thrown here *


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

I can share any of the other code if it's needed. Any help appreciated, since I don't know what's wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused as you have not required your package `discord.js` as to a single constant `Discord`, you see every package is a module which has various properties and functions as displayed below:

[image: components of discord.js]

At the very top of your file you are destructuring these components from the module discord.js so you very well need to destructure the Collection too! like so:

```js
    const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError, Collection } = require('discord.js');     
    // then you may define it like so    
    client.commands = new Collection()
```

This would be absolutely valid as you can see here:
[image: display]

Comment: This worked, and thanks a bunch for the explanation! It was really helpful for understanding what I did :)

Answer (score 0):

add this at the top of your code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of autocorrect. You should delete `DiscordAPIError` on Line 1 and add this line below it:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

This way each time you say say `Discord` it invokes discord.js

That will solve your problem!